# Git Configuration with eclipse--not able to push code from eclipse to remote git server

Tags: linux, git, repository, centos

1)I have just configured GIT on my local centos 6.4 server and created a repository 
2)Generated key also and kept at server
2)I am able to checkout code from this remote server to my dev machine in eclipse no problem till here

But when I tried to push code from Eclipse the it always says that "Can't connect to any repository: ssh://homepage@1.1.1.1/var/git/demo/ (An internal Exception occured during push: ssh://homepage@1.1.1.1/var/git/demo/: error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit)"

Not sure why ? Is there anything which i missed ?

Comment: Is pushing using command line working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the permission on the directories

Comment: Hi Mitul.How have you changed the permissions and on which directories? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a permissions issue on the repo. I had the same problem, but was using Netbeans. Managed to temporarily fix it by giving 777 permissions to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this. It was due to something else, a bit stupid, really. I put a bare repository inside of a bare repository and expected them to behave individually. Once I moved the file structure of the inner bare repository out, it worked.

I just had to change the remote configuration of the local repository to point to the new location (outside of the other repo).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when checking into Git via Eclipse (EGit). The root cause turned out as space crunch on Git server. After deleting some unused projects we were able to checkin the code.